# Correct terminology for pointer types

Tags: c

If I use `int *p;` then which of the following is more correct to say:

- p is of type pointer-to-int, or
- p points to an int and is of type pointer

What I mean to determine is what is the best way to describe how to look at such code and understand the difference between, say `int *p;` and `char *c;` with regard to type.

PS: I understand pointers myself, but wish to explain them correctly to my team-mates who do not, hopefully to give them an easy way to cope with parsing code that uses pointers

Comment: What's wrong with "pointer to int"? I don't understand the second alternative. If `p` points to something, it is obvious it is of a pointer type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I want to break down the elements of the declaration for the purpose of easing comprehension for my team mates. "pointer to int" mixes up the elements of the statement which, as it is written are int, then pointer, then name.

Comment: Look at https://cdecl.org/ and give it to your teammates.

Comment: To clarify, I guess I dont want to give the idea that there is a type called pointer-to-int.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the cdecl mention, I already knew it but it jogged something in my mind "pointer statements can be read from the inside out", i.e. This is a pointer. To an int. Named p.

Comment: If someone can't understand "pointer to int", "pointer to char", etc,  they should start with textbooks before getting into any "teams" :)

Comment: The more interesting case is when you have some type qualifiers such as `volatile`. Now explain the difference between `volatile int *p` and `int* volatile p`.

Comment: If you need to explain code to teammates that don't comprehend the pointers in said code, pretending that the code doesn't contain pointers at all is a dangerous backwards step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `p` is *"pointer to `int`"*.

You can say that `p` is *a* pointer, but you can't say that it's *type* is just *"pointer"*.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to say: 'p' is of type: *"int pointer*". That should be clear and concise. There is no need to philosophize and complicate matters.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am hearing pretty often. Surely it is incorrect, but clear what it is referring to.

Comment: Well, the actual type is "int *", but if you want to read it in english, you'd say pointer for the asterisk

Comment: @EugeneSh.: YMMV

Answer (score 0):

The only place that I'm aware of that describes a pointer variable as having "pointer type" is the Standard (C11 6.7.9, for example):

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - **if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;**
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>     and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>     rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

But it only does that when discussing types in the abstract. Whenever "real world" objects are discussed, the Standard usually uses the "pointer to *type*" phrase (C11 6.2.5, for example):

> 29 EXAMPLE 1 The type designated as ‘‘float *’’ has type ‘‘pointer to float’’. Its type category is
>   pointer, not a floating type. The const-qualified version of this type is designated as ‘‘float * const’’
>   whereas the type designated as ‘‘const float *’’ is not a qualified type — its type is ‘‘pointer to const-

Comment: Here "pointer type" does not mean some concrete type, but a family of types. Such as "integral type" or "floating point type"

Comment: @EugeneSh: Yes, it refers more to the "type category" as mentioned in the second block quote. And as I say, that is only ever used when the Standard is speaking in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

For any type `T` and declaration `T *p;`, the type of `p` is "pointer to `T`", or `T *`.

There is no single "pointer" type.  All pointer types are distinct, and named in reference to the base type.